# Does a Fourier series always have period $2\pi$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If you do the Fourier series for $\sin{3x}$

The frequency is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and the period is $2\pi$ ?

How does the Fourier series model $\sin{3x}$ ?

Comment: No, a fourier series can have an arbitrary finite period. See section definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series. No, the period is $2\pi/3$. The fourier series models $\sin(3x)$ by simly setting the coefficients of all the cosine terms to zero. The same is done for all the coefficients of the sine terms, with one exeption the $\sin(3x)$ term, where the coefficient is 1.

Comment: okay.... so if P=2pi, when x = 3, P=2pi/3 does that mean that L = pi/3 does that also mean that it is Px=2pi ?

Comment: Yes if you function is $\sin(kx)$ then the Period $P=\frac{2\pi}{k}$

Comment: Is this something specific to the Fourier series in terms of how the coefficients are calculated ? I don't understand how the k from sinkx ends up in pk = 2pi

Comment: Just look up the derivation/motivation for the fourier series. Actually you assume that your periodic function has this representation, then you multiply by $\sin(kx)$ or $\cos(kx)$ and integrate from $c$ to $c+P$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 2):

Fourier series have period $p=\frac{2\pi}{m}$ for $\sin(mx)$, so the period of $\sin(3x)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, ie, $p=\frac{2\pi}{3}$. The more general form of a Fourier series with period $p$ has the following representation:
$$
S_R(x)= \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum^{R}_{\xi=1}a_{\xi}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi \xi x}{p}\right)+b_{\xi}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi \xi x}{p}\right) \\
=\sum_{|\xi|\leq R}c_{\xi}e^{\frac{2\pi i\xi\cdot x}{p}}.
$$
Here, we have the integrals
$$
a_0=\int^{x_0+p}_{x_0}f(x)dx,~ 
a_{\xi}=\frac{2}{p}\int^{x_0+p}_{x_0}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi\xi x}{p}\right)dx \\
b_{\xi}=\frac{2}{p}\int^{x_0+p}_{x_0}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\xi x}{p}\right)dx,~ 
c_{\xi}=\frac{1}{p}\int^{x_0+p}_{x_0}f(x)e^{-\frac{2\pi i\xi x}{p}}dx \\
$$

So you will need to proceed as you would in the same way as you do for Fourier series with period $2\pi$ functions, but use this new adjusted formula. Can you do this yourself?